# How to increase size of filesystems in linux cli?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have some partitions out of size. Can I make room for them?

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            476M     0  476M   0% /dev
tmpfs            98M  808K   98M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1       15G  7.5G  7.1G  52% /
tmpfs           490M     0  490M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           490M     0  490M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           490M  8.0K  490M   1% /tmp
/dev/loop2       34M   34M     0 100% /snap/agent/3552
/dev/loop1       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1006
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
```

I tried this one but it didn't work

```
vresize -L+100M /dev/loop0 /dev/xvda1:0-1 /dev/xvda1:0-1
```

"/dev/loop0": Invalid path for Logical Volume.

Comment: If you used lvresize (not vresize) then that would be for a LVM system. You don't have Logical Volumes etc.

Comment: Add the output of `fdisk -l | grep xvda` as root to your question.

Comment: How can increase the size of /dev/loop2 then? @JeremyBoden

Comment: Do you have any errors saying that you have insufficient storage/memory for any processes?

Comment: Yes I do. I use OSSEC and receive lots of emails with the alert Level 7 - Partition usage reached 100% (disk space monitor). That's how I found this. I'm just looking a way to fix this issue. @JeremyBoden

Answer (score 0):

The [loop devices](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/loop.4.html) used by [snap](https://snapcraft.io/) packages are supposed to be using 100 % of the space, that's normal. Snaps [are squashfs images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/842093/how-do-snaps-work-exactly-and-why-are-they-mounted) that are mounted using loop devices, they don't need extra space and you can't resize them.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I receive lots of alerts from OSSEC — Level 7 - Partition usage reached 100% (disk space monitor). In this case, how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Use less disk storage. Do you have extra storage not shown in the question?

Comment: I'm not familiar with OSSEC, I found [this issue](https://github.com/ossec/ossec-hids/issues/1418) on their github, there are some suggestions for workarounds/custom rules there. If this doesn't work, I'd recommend asking a new question about this.

Comment: @VojtechTrefny thanks for sharing that suggestion. It didn't work on my end. I just asked it as [a new question.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/656053/how-to-delete-or-fix-ossec-alert-level-7-partition-usage-reached-100-disk-sp)